# SQL XML Parsing Stored Procedure running manually, not running via SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sql-server-agent

The stored Procedure is running manually but will not run using SQL Server agent.

**I get the following error**

> Executed as user: XXX. XML parsing: line 9, character 9, unexpected
>   end of input [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 9400).  The step failed.

The stored Procedure takes the xml from a web query, puts it in a single cell in a temp table. Parses the data from the temp table and puts the new easy-to-read information into a permanent table. I need the query to run daily and fetch the data for that day.

I've tried looking up the issue but the only clue I have is that the XML is being chopped somewhere. I have no idea why this is happening for a job only.

Any help you could give would be great.

Thanks

EDIT1: I've split the procedure into 7 different steps. This is the Step it is falling down on.

`INSERT XMLData(XMLD)
SELECT CAST(HTML AS XML) As XMLData FROM TextData`

EDIT2: Here's the code

```
DECLARE 

@url varchar(2048),
@win integer,
@hr integer ,
@text varchar(MAX),
@XMLdata XML,
@Date date,
@SearchDate nvarchar(50) 


Set @Date = GETDATE()

set @SearchDate = CAST(@Date as nvarchar(50))

set @SearchDate = REPLACE(@SearchDate,'-','')


--set @SearchDate='20130405'

/*-- Create Temporary tables to be used to store the xml data--*/
/*-- We need 2 tables as the raw data from SEMO is Unicode 'UTF-8' but SQL only handles 'UTF-16'--*/
/*-- We must therefore store the data first as Text and then CAST it to XML datatype for easy querying later --*/
CREATE TABLE #TextData(HTML text NULL)
CREATE TABLE #XMLData(XMLD xml NULL)

/*-- This url will have to be dynamically generated each day based on GetDate() query or similiar - to be cracked out fully - random date picked for now--*/
Select @url = 'http://.......'

/* Use OLE Automation Objects to go out and get the data--*/    
EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open',NULL,'GET',@url,'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win,'Send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

INSERT #TextData(HTML)
EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win,'ResponseText'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

/*-- Now CAST the text data to XML data type which makes it much easier to query back--*/
INSERT #XMLData(XMLD)
SELECT CAST(HTML AS XML) As XMLData FROM #TextData



/*-- WE NEED TO ADD IN A SECTION HERE NOW TO PARSE THE XML DATA AND EXTRACT THE INFO WE NEED INTO A DEDICATED TABLED--*/

/*-- Replace the : in the #XMLData table with _ as the colons were causing errors --*/
UPDATE #XMLData
SET XMLD = REPLACE(CAST(XMLD as varchar(max)),':' ,'_')
FROM #XMLData
WHERE CHARINDEX(':' ,CAST(XMLD as varchar(max)))>0

UPDATE #XMLData
SET XMLD = REPLACE(CAST(XMLD as varchar(max)),'DataSet xmlns="http_//localhost/SemoReporting/SemoAutomatedDataCollection/Datasets"' ,'DataSet')
FROM #XMLData
WHERE CHARINDEX('DataSet xmlns="http_//localhost/SemoReporting/SemoAutomatedDataCollection/Datasets"' ,CAST(XMLD as varchar(max)))>0

Select @XMLdata = XMLD
FROM #XMLData

/*-- This is to show the colons have been replaced --*/
SELECT * FROM #XMLData

Declare @i as int
set @i = 1

While @i < 97
BEGIN
/*Insert Data into SEMO Historical Table*/

INSERT INTO XMLParsing.dbo.T1301_SEMO_HISTORICAL_DATA 
/*-- This selects the relevant data from table1 element --*/
SELECT
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/CURRENCY_FLAG[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS [Currency],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/TRADE_DATE[1]','date') AS [Trade Date],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/DELIVERY_DATE[1]','date') AS [Delivery Date],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/DELIVERY_HOUR[1]','int') AS [Delivery Hour],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/DELIVERY_INTERVAL[1]','int') AS [Delivery Interval],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/RUN_TYPE[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS [Run Type],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/SMP[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS [SMP],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/LAMBDA[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS [Lambda],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/SYSTEM_LOAD[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS [System Load],
a.b.value('Table1[sql:variable("@i")][1]/CMS_TIME_STAMP[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS [CMS Time Stamp]
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('DataSet/diffgr_diffgram/EA_RESULTS') a(b)
--where 
--not exists (Select * from SEMO_Historical_Data where [Trade Date] = @Date)
set @i=@i+1
END

Drop Table #TextData
Drop Table #XMLData
```

Comment: You are going to have to show us some code in order for us to help you.  Specifically, we'll need to see you Job Step definition and your stored procedure.

Comment: If something works when you run it but not when you scheduled it, it's almost always either permissions or environment. Scheduled jobs run as the SQL Server Agent service account by default, and that account may not have access to all the system resources that your account does. Or the server where you schedule the job doesn't have the same drivers or configuration that your test server does. But without more information about exactly what the procedure does, it's hard to say what the problem really is.

Comment: @JenniferNolan Post the whole procedure (or any subset that can reproduce the problem).  The problem is being caused earlier in the code.    Also post the Job Step's SQL command text.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. The reason this wasn't working correctly is that the XML being taken from the site was being truncated. I never fully figured out why this was happening but i used wget for windows instead of WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 which took all the data from the site and passed it directly to a webpage from which I could parse the data.